# Where is output console in Rider?

Tags: c#, rider

Rider 2021
windows 10
C#

Where is output console in Rider?

Program error, but no log
[image]

Comment: Are you not highlighting the console output in your linked image?  That's where exit code is. Are you looking for build log, warning?

Comment: This site is english only, please remove your comment and rewrite in english.

Comment: Their question is highlighting that the application is not outputting the `----------------` text. One quick solution is to right-click the project and switch the type from Library or Desktop Application to a Console Application.